# The emails are not sending to larger companies like Chase bank etc

Tags: wordpress, email, dns, google-workspace

I setup the emails on Google Workspace using my website domain (i.e xyz@mywebsite.com).

Basically what is  going on is people are sending me emails, but their internal servers are blocking them and blocking from me sending to them as well. In other situations they’re able to send me emails but once I send them the email back, they are not receiving them.

This is only happening to larger companies like (Chase bank, Home Depot etc) and they are saying it has to do with my domain.

I don't know where is the problem, in website, DNS, email or Google Wordspace. I put some records in DNS editor.